# Two variables referencing the same collection

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I have the following fragments of code (suppose `x` is of type `Integer[]`):

```
Collection<Integer> col1 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x));
Collection<Integer> col2 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x));
```

After the second line, is it true that `col1` and `col2` reference the same collection?

Comment: this will help http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/25/object-references-and-assignment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The two variables refer to two different `TreeSet` instances that happen to contain the same elements. Each constructor call (`new TreeSet<Integer>`) produces a different instance of `TreeSet`.

In order for both variables to refer to the same instance, you'll need to assign one to the other :

```
Collection<Integer> col1 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x));
Collection<Integer> col2 = col1;
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider sure

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean with "same".

`col1` and `col2` will refer to two different `TreeSet` objects, since separate objects are created in the two different uses of the `new` operator. If you add or remove elements to or from one of them that will not affect the other. In that sense they are definitely different.

But they represent the same collection of elements. In Java comparisons with the `equals` method are very common and important, and the two different `TreeSet` objects will be considered equal by that method. So in some sense they are kind of the same (at least until one of them is modified).

The first sense of the word "same" is the usual one in the context of Java programming. The second sense is very important too, but that is usually called "equality".

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Every time you create an object using the `new` keyword, a new object with a new `identity` will  be created. For example,

```
Collection<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Collection<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
TreeSet<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<>(list2);

System.out.println(set==set2); // false, reference equality
System.out.println(set.equals(set2)); // true, value equality
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extending **Eran's** post

```
Integer[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    Collection<Integer> col1 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x));
    Collection<Integer> col2 = col1;
```

In the above code `col2` refers `col1` `TreeSet<Integer>` object

So in this case if you try to change any one object the other will change as well

```
col1.add(7);
System.out.println(col2.toString());
```

In the above code, 7 is added to `col1` object, but it is also appears to be added to  `col2` as `col2` refers to `col1` and `col2` yields output as

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Same goes for below code

```
col2.add(8);
System.out.println(col1.toString());
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

They will refer to the same collection of objects but in actual are different objects.
Please try this test class:
public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer[] arr=new Integer[]{12,10};
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).hashCode());
  Collection<Integer> col1 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
  Collection<Integer> col2 = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
  System.out.println(col1.hashCode()+":"+col2.hashCode());
  System.out.println(col1.equals(col2));
```

System.out.println(col1==col2);//false
    }

}

Comment: hashCode and equals equality doesn't mean they have the same identity